# Can this Smooth Scrolling script be implemented and work with a Next.js and React environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, smooth-scrolling

I have a parallax effect on my website and want to smooth it out with some smooth scrolling but this Script I cannot seem to work with my Next.js and React Environment, I have tried different kinds of smooth scrolling libraries from Github and none of them seems to work with my environment?

Are there any problems with this code here that stops it from being executed in my environment?

```
init() {
        new SmoothScroll(document, 120, 12)
    }

    SmoothScroll(target, speed, smooth) {
        if (target === document)
            target = (document.scrollingElement
                || document.documentElement
                || document.body.parentNode
                || document.body) // cross browser support for document scrolling

        var moving = false
        var pos = target.scrollTop
        var frame = target === document.body
            && document.documentElement
            ? document.documentElement
            : target // safari is the new IE

        target.addEventListener('mousewheel', scrolled, { passive: false })
        target.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', scrolled, { passive: false })

        function scrolled(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // disable default scrolling

            var delta = normalizeWheelDelta(e)

            pos += -delta * speed
            pos = Math.max(0, Math.min(pos, target.scrollHeight - frame.clientHeight)) // limit scrolling

            if (!moving) update()
        }

        function normalizeWheelDelta(e) {
            if (e.detail) {
                if (e.wheelDelta)
                    return e.wheelDelta / e.detail / 40 * (e.detail > 0 ? 1 : -1) // Opera
                else
                    return -e.detail / 3 // Firefox
            } else
                return e.wheelDelta / 120 // IE,Safari,Chrome
        }

        function update() {
            moving = true

            var delta = (pos - target.scrollTop) / smooth

            target.scrollTop += delta

            if (Math.abs(delta) > 0.5)
                requestFrame(update)
            else
                moving = false
        }

        var requestFrame = function () { // requestAnimationFrame cross browser
            return (
                window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
                window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
                function (func) {
                    window.setTimeout(func, 1000 / 50);
                }
            );
        }()
    }
```

Comment: what file are you using calling init() in? what errors are being logged?

Comment: Use wheel instead of mousewheel. Mousewheel is deprecated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?